# Concurrency Thread Group and Throughput shaping timer

Tags: jmeter

I want to simulate 100 rps for the application which I am working on. I am planning to use Concurrency Thread Group and Throughput shaping timer. I have created a sample example to test how it works. Below is my script

[image]
[image]
[image: Aggregate Report]

I have added this as the next line to log4j2.xml file:

```
<Logger name="kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer" level="debug" />
```

jmeter.log has below logs

```
2021-07-21 14:11:22,402 INFO c.b.j.c.VirtualUserController: Need to decrease concurrency, thread is done: bzm - Concurrency Thread Group-ThreadStarter 1-217
2021-07-21 14:11:22,402 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: bzm - Concurrency Thread Group-ThreadStarter 1-217
2021-07-21 14:11:22,402 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: bzm - Concurrency Thread Group-ThreadStarter 1-217
2021-07-21 14:11:22,407 DEBUG k.a.j.t.VariableThroughputTimer: Calculating 407 380.0 38
2021-07-21 14:11:22,427 INFO c.b.j.c.VirtualUserController: Need to decrease concurrency, thread is done: bzm - Concurrency Thread Group-ThreadStarter 1-218
2021-07-21 14:11:22,427 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: bzm - Concurrency Thread Group-ThreadStarter 1-218
2021-07-21 14:11:22,427 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: bzm - Concurrency Thread Group-ThreadStarter 1-218
........
........
2021-07-21 14:11:23,007 DEBUG k.a.j.t.VariableThroughputTimer: Second changed 60.0 , waiting: 0, samples sent 94, current rps: 100.0 rps
2021-07-21 14:11:23,007 WARN k.a.j.t.VariableThroughputTimer: No free threads available in current Thread Group bzm - Concurrency Thread Group, made 94 samples/s for expected rps 100.0 samples/s, increase your number of threads
2021-07-21 14:11:23,007 DEBUG k.a.j.t.VariableThroughputTimer: Calculating 7 0.0 0
```

My question is

Q1. Have I configured my test correctly to simulate throughput of 100 rps or am I missing something ?

Q2. How do I calculate in advance how many users do I need to add in Target Concurrency? If I go with the formula

```
(rps * Maximum response time) / 1000
```

Here, do I need to add the Maximum response time of all the samplers from 1 to 6? or how?

Q3. How do we calculate the throughput?(refer 3rd image having Aggregate Report),

Is the Total Throughput = Adding Throughput of Sampler 1 to 6, which is = (15.8 + 15.8 + 15.8 + 15.7 + 15.6 + 15.6) = 94.3 rps. Is my calculation correct?

Q4. In the jmeter.log, it says "Need to decrease concurrency, thread is done: bzm - Concurrency Thread Group-ThreadStarter 1-217".

Does that mean number of threads(users) needed to simulate 100 rps are more and hence jmeter needs to decrease the threads(users)?

Then again in the logs, it says, "No free threads available in current Thread Group bzm - Concurrency Thread Group, made 94 samples/s for expected rps 100.0 samples/s, increase your number of threads"

Is it asking me (the user) to increase the thread or it is just the jmeter talking to itself? Jmeter already has 150 threads to use. Actually I started from 50 and then also I received the message to increase the no of threads then I increased the threads to 100 and I got the same message and then finally I increased it to 150 and still getting that message in the logs?

[image]

As you can see for the above image, at the 51th second, jmeter was using only 29 threads(users) out of 150. Which means it still has 121 threads left to use. Also, I observed that when I started the script, immediately 150 threads were in use but then they started rapidly decreasing and increasing. However, they never been to 150 during the 60 seconds run (150 threads wered used only at the start, for a fraction of seconds and then got reduced!)

Then why was the message in the logs to increase the users? infact there are users available which jmeter can use?

Answer (score 0):

You only forgot to ask the "Q5": the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything

- Q1. We don't know, it depends on the application response time, your 150 threads may or may not be sufficient to conduct the load of 100 requests per second
- Q2. Go for the largest response time ever, according to JMeter threads model each thread waits for the previous request to finish before starting the next one so the whole sequence of 6 samplers will act at the speed of the slowest one.
- Q3. Throughput Shaping Timer tries to reach and maintain the defined throughput for all the samplers in its [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) so if you have 6 requests in scope the throughput for individual request would be 100 / 6
- Q4. `Need to decrease concurrency` - the timer is "talking to itself" informing that it goes too fast hence need to shut down a couple of threads to slow down the requests rate. `increase your number of threads` is for you but I don't think it's applicable for your case, if you run the real test and will see tons of messages like this in the log it will indicate that the current amount is not sufficient to reach the target throughput
- Don't run your test in GUI mode, it's only for tests development and debugging, when it comes to execution you [must be using command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
- [According to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page